# Finding matrix inverse using Gauss method

Tags: matrices, inverse, gaussian-elimination

I have been trying to find the inverse of a matrix using Gauss method and I want to know suppose what happens if I don't get the "1" in reduced matrix on the left? Does it mean that the inverse doesn't exist?

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 :   1 & 2 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 :   0 &-3 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 :   1 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Yes, a matrix A is invertible if and only if it is row reducible to the identity matrix.

Comment: What does it mean to find the inverse really? I am guessing it would mean that the values of $x, y, z$ of linear equations will have reciprocal values of original matrix?

Comment: Not at all, this is not what finding the inverse means. A matrix $B$ is an inverse matrix of $A$ if and only if $AB = I$ and $BA = I$ where $I$ is the identity matrix. Actually, with this definition, one can prove that a necessary condition for a matrix to be invertible is that the matrix is square.